# Angular 7 | mat-tab active | styles not reflected

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

> 

```
<div class="navigation">
>         <mat-tab-group disableRipple="true"  selectedIndex="0">
>             <mat-tab label="Label1"> </mat-tab>
>             <mat-tab label="label 2">  </mat-tab>
>             <mat-tab label="Label 3">  </mat-tab>
>         </mat-tab-group>
>     </div>
```

The above is my html, I want to select label1 as a default tab.
However, active style is not getting applied when I say selectedIndex="0", but getting applied when I click on the tab.

When my tab is active, the tab label color is white. This is not the case when the tab is selected by default using selectedIndex="0".

I am using angular7.
Below are the material tab styles in my component css

CSS Styles related to Material Tab:

> 

```
.mat-ink-bar{
>         background-color: #ffffff !important;
>         border-bottom-color:solid #FFFFFF!important;
>         width: 113px !important;
>         height:4px !important;
>         margin-left: 2rem;
>         margin-bottom:0px;
>         
>     }
>     
>     .mat-tab-label, .mat-tab-label-active{
>         color:#FFFFFF;
>         background-color: transparent;
>         font-family: "verdana";
>         font-size: 20px;
>         font-weight:500;
>         max-width: 113px;
>         padding: 0px;
>         margin:0px;
>     }
```

Please suggest. Thanks ahead.
Apologies for the bad formatting.

Comment: May be you are changing something in component, on init.
I try above code it's working https://stackblitz.com/angular/jyxexraedvg

Answer (score 0):

> Below are the material tab styles *in my component css*

Your style will not work in your component CSS because the tab component styles are encapsulated. You will need to either place your style in your global style sheet, or use the deep combinator:

```
/deep/ .mat-tab-ink-bar {
   ...
}
```

Also, your style applies the same styling to *all* tab labels both active and not:

```
.mat-tab-label, .mat-tab-label-active {
```

should probably be

```
.mat-tab-label.mat-tab-label-active {
```

or just `.mat-tab-label-active`.

Comment: FYI `/deep/` is to be deprecated so using `:host` selector will be best

Comment: `:host` is not an alternative to `/deep/` - it is something else entirely. However, it is good to point out that `/deep/` is already deprecated even though browsers have not stopped supporting it yet.

Answer (score 0):

Few years late but maybe this will help someone.

I am using Angular 14 with Material 14.

I used devtools Elements inspector to inspect styles on the material tabs and came up with this solution (see below.)  Now the active tab always looks active even when it loses focus (e.g. if you click into the content part or somewhere else on the page.)

Put this in the scss for your component:

```
:host ::ng-deep {
  .mat-tab-label-active {
      opacity: 1; // <-- this is the magic
  }
}
```